# How to download plots made in a shiny app(in a jpeg /png format )

Tags: shiny

I'm trying to figure out how to use downloadButton to download a plot with shiny. The example in the package demonstrates downloadButton/downloadHandler to save a .pdf. I'm going to make a reproducible example based on that.

```
    output$downloadPlot <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
        "plotname .pdf"
    },

    content = function(file) {
        pdf(file = file,
                width = 12,
                height = 12)
        print(buildPlot())
        dev.off()
    }
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you to use Highcharter package. This way you don't need to create a download button, because the chart has options to download in several extensions. Here I give you an example of an histogram, choosing to export in PNG, SVG, JPEG or PDF.

```r
## Export charts with Highcharter in Shiny

# Load package
library('highcharter')

# UI side
highchartOutput('plot')

# Server side
output$plot <- renderHighchart({
  
  # Define your data, here I am using Iris dataset as example
  DT <- iris$Sepal.Length 
  
  # Define export options
  export <- list(
    list(
      text = "PNG",
      onclick = JS("function () {
                   this.exportChart({ type: 'image/png' }); }")
      ),
    list(
      text = "JPEG",
      onclick = JS("function () {
                   this.exportChart({ type: 'image/jpeg' }); }")
      ),
    list(
      text = "SVG",
      onclick = JS("function () {
                   this.exportChart({ type: 'image/svg+xml' }); }")
      ),
    list(
      text = "PDF",
      onclick = JS("function () {
                   this.exportChart({ type: 'application/pdf' }); }")
      )
    )
  
  # Plot histogram
  hchart(DT,
    type = "area",
    name = colnames(iris[1])
  ) %>%
    hc_exporting(
      enabled = TRUE,
      formAttributes = list(target = "_blank"),
      buttons = list(contextButton = list(
        text = "Export",
        theme = list(fill = "transparent"),
        menuItems = export
      ))
    )
})
```

The output should be something like this:
[image]

Hope this helps.

Wlademir.

Comment: Is possible add Power Point in the download Options?, if yes,  how can i do it?